# Only fire one onmouseover when hovering over multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have basic code like the following:

```
<span onmouseover="alert('hi')">Hello, <span onmouseover="alert('hello')">this</span> is a test</span>
```

However, I'd like to keep it from firing both of these events if both are being hovered over; e.g. if I hover over "this" it should fire only its event and alert "hello." How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use `alert()` for debugging, and especially not for this kind of debugging. Use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant portion of what I ended up using. I used JQuery.

```
var mouseHovered = function(element) {
    //get all hovered spans
    var hoveredElements = $("span:hover");
    //get the element with the smallest text
    var smallestElement;
    for(var i=0; i<hoveredElements.length; i++) if(!smallestElement || hoveredElements[i].textContent.length < smallestElement.textContent.length) smallestElement = hoveredElements[i];
    //if this is the smallest text in the elements
    if(element == smallestElement) {
        //log the text
        console.log(element.textContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".container").hover(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="container" id="hi">
Hello,
</span>
<span class="container" id="hello">
this
</span>
<span class="container" id="hi">
is a test
</span>
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. Hover over "this" and you can see that it alerts first "hello" (correct behavior) and then "hi" (incorrect behavior).

Comment: Fixed it I had unclosed span tag

Comment: Now you've got an unmatched </span> tag on the end of your code and as a result "is a test" has no hover. You could duplicate the <span> declaration you've got on "Hello" for "is a test," but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No change: the engine ignored the ending </span> tag already so by removing it we're still right where we were.

Comment: Hope this is what you expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158244/discussion-between-black-mamba-and-jasper-r).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the overlapping elements are not the same size. I.e one is bigger than the other.

HTML and inline js:

```
<span class="container" id="hi"> 
 Hello, 
 </span> 
 <span class="container " id="hello">
 this </span>
<script>
 var hello =   
document.getElementById("hello");          
   var this =       
  document.getElementById
    ("this");
    hello.addEventListener("click
   ",pop("hello"));                                                                  


this.addEventListener("click",pop(" hi");
 function pop(string) {
 window.alert(string);
}
 <\script>
```

That being said very little is mentioned about the nature of the elements this and hello. Op plz show your CSS and update ques

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent `Event bubbling` when you `hover/click` on inner span.
This can be done using [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Look at two solutions provided at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/fa42fva7/3/).

**Solution 1 -** Use of `e.stopPropagation()` in the handler function `innerSpan()`.

**Solution 2 -** Use of `event.stopPropagation()` in inline `onclick` event.

```
<span onclick="alert('Outer span');">
    Outer
    <span onclick="event.stopPropagation(); alert('Inner span');">
        Inner
    </span>
</span>
```